# Printing multidimensional array only prints first column

Tags: c

So I have a spreadsheet stored in the form of a multidimensional array, and I'm trying to make a function that prints the contents of a row. Unfortunately, it seems to only print the first value, and the rest of the prints are blank. What could be the reason for this?

```
// Outputs the specified row of the spreadsheet.
// It is printed as one line on standard output.
void SS_PrintRow(SPREADSHEET *ss, int rowNum) {
    if (debug)
        fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG: Call to SS_PrintRow(--,%d)\n", rowNum);
    // TO BE COMPLETED!
    if(rowNum >= MAXROWS || rowNum < 0){
        printf("-- row number outside range\n");
        return;
    }
    SPREADSHEET read;
    memcpy(&read,ss,sizeof(*ss));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < MAXCOLS ;i++){
        read.contents[rowNum][i][MAXLEN] = '\0'; // force null termination
        printf("%s ",read.contents[rowNum][i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Row values:

```
Jane,24,122.3,brunette
```

Output:

```
Jane
```

EDIT: Here is the SPREADSHEET struct.

```
struct SpreadSheet {
    char *fileName;
    int  numRows;
    int  numCols;
    char contents[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS][MAXLEN];
};

typedef struct SpreadSheet SPREADSHEET;
```

Comment: 1) Posting the complete definition of `SPREADSHEET` would help.  2) note: `memcpy(&read,ss,sizeof(*ss));` would be cleaner as  `read = *ss;`.

Comment: Added the definition of SPREADSHEET. Also, memcpy is formatted as you said, is it not?

Comment: Good you have your answer to the post.  Concerning my comment, recommend use `read = *ss;` and not `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
read.contents[rowNum][i][MAXLEN] = '\0'
```

this exceeds the boundaries of your array by one element. Recall that C-based arrays are indexed with `0...(len-1)`. With your structure defined as:

```
struct SpreadSheet 
{
    char *fileName;
    int  numRows;
    int  numCols;
    char contents[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS][MAXLEN];
};
```

the offending line should be:

```
read.contents[rowNum][i][MAXLEN-1] = '\0';
```

and I pray `rowNum` is properly zero-based as well, though it at-least-appears it probably is.

Comment: This made it print the rest, but now it's also printing garbage characters, which was the reason I even have that line to begin with. Do I need to do something different to avoid the garbage?

Comment: @user3283585 The code that populates the original strings is likely not terminating them. That code isn't shown here. Frankly I see no reason this termination should be done in the first place if that code were properly terminating the strings in the first place.

Comment: rowNum is zero-based, yes.

Comment: The code was something supplied. It [*seems*](http://hastebin.com/orupahalug.avrasm) to terminate, as far as I can tell anyway...